# A function is differentiable at every x $\notin$ Z and not differentiable at every x $\in$ Z

Tags: real-analysis

There are some conditions that i would like to state first:

f is strictly increasing.

f:R $\mapsto$R.

Z is all integers.

So essentially what i have found is that i need to use a piece wise function, or i also have considered using the step function. The problem states to give an example and draw a picture so not too many heavey proofs are needed but.
I know that i have to satisfy the definition of strictly increasing and differentiability. that is fine.

so my example that i created is:

x if x $\notin$ Z

ln(x) if x $\in$ Z

And the graph of this function would look like the line $y = x$ with holes at every integer intersection and then the normal graph of $y = ln(x)$ this would in my understanding satisfy the conditions and answer the question appropriatly. especially after i use some examples to satisfy the defintions of strictly increasing, and differentiable and non differentiable

I would like to know if there are any holes in my logic or if there are any suggestions to tweak the rigor my desired answer. I would just like some second opinions on my approach. i appreciate any feedback thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your function is not strictly increasing because for $\varepsilon < 1$ and $n \in \Bbb N^*$, $f(n+\varepsilon)=\ln(n+\varepsilon)<n=f(n)$

To get an increasing function, the easiest example is probably

$x\mapsto \lfloor x\rfloor$ but then, it's not strictly increasing.

So you take $x\mapsto \lfloor x\rfloor +\cfrac{1}{2}(x - \lfloor x\rfloor)$

It looks like $x\mapsto \cfrac{1}{2} x$ except that at every integer, you jump up by $\cfrac{1}{2}.$

[image]

Answer (score 2):

How about $2\,\pi\,x+|\sin(\pi\,x)|$?

Comment: It seems pretty smooth to me...

Comment: I forgot the absolute value!